# 3.5" SAS drives in server with 2.5" bays

Tags: storage, sas, rackmount

We recently acquired a very cheap 2nd-hand server (HP ProLiant DL380 G7).

We have a number of 3.5" SAS drives, however the server only has mount points for 2.5" bays.

We would still like to leverage them, in the most cost effective way of getting these drives connected to the server.

We are a small operation, and don't mind if things are a bit messy, or if we potentially shorten the life of the drives by not having good mounting - this is a budget rig not used for any core production.

I'm looking at [this internal SAS cable form Startech](https://www.startech.com/Cables/Drive/SAS/50cm-Internal-Serial-Attached-SCSI-Mini-SAS-Cable-SFF8087-to-4x-FF8482%7ESAS808782P50), to connect the drives to the server, and then just have them sitting in a pile or whatever.

Would this work, or are there a better options?

[This question is very similar](https://serverfault.com/questions/333786/how-to-implement-cheap-lff-3-5-sata-storage-on-a-hp-proliant-ml350-g6-with-2-5), though a number of years old and I'm unsure what backplane and cages would be compatible, available, and cheap for this server ((HP ProLiant DL380 G7)).

Comment: This isn't a good forum for junkyard hardware.

Comment: That server's hit it's EoSL, I *think* the drive cages in them were swappable at the time but you won't be able to find the spare parts to do it now. Perhaps someone might be selling the chassis of the 3.5" version without anything else, you could buy that and swap all the parts over from your existing 2.5" ancient version - or just buy a raspberry pi or NUC, probably be faster.

Comment: "Can I fit 10 gallons of water in a 5 gallon bucket?" - No, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

This can't really be done without physically damaging the chassis.  There's just no way to get a 3.5" disk into a 2.5" slot.  MAYBE with something like this - [https://www.amazon.com/Drive-SFF-8482-Cable-Female-Extension/dp/B00HIBHA3E](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HIBHA3E)  but I wouldn't count on that working for long, if at all.  The chassis are designed for airflow, so if your drives are sitting outside the chassis, they basically won't get any and could overheat.